# Firebase functions SDK 1.0.0 storage.onFinalize() not working as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I use Firebase function to detect an upload event to Storage and write the download URL to the database like so:

```
exports.processFile = functions.storage.object().onChange((event) => {
  const object = event.data,
        filePath = object.name;

  if (object.resourceState === 'exists') {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Getting an email about the SDK 1.0 I updated the function like this:

```
exports.processFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object, context) => {
  const filePath = object.name;

  if (object.resourceState === 'exists') {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

After the update, the function  broke so I decided to print the `resourceState` in the log and got an `undefined`. What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before SDK 1.0 there was only the [onChange()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/beta/functions.storage.ObjectBuilder#onChange) event.  It fired for all changes to the storage object and one had to test [resourceState](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/beta/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata#resourceState) in the object metadata to determine if the change was a creation, update, or deletion.

In SDK 1.0, `onChange()` has been [replaced by four events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#storage), eliminating the need to test the value of `resourceState`:

- onArchive()
- onDelete()
- onFinalize()
- onMetadataUpdate()

Although the documentation for [ObjectMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata) still shows `resourceState`, my guess is that it has been removed from SDK 1.0 because it is no longer needed.

Comment: Hmm... That's a good guess. I wish the Firebase team would manage their documentation better. This is not the first time I had confusion because different documents would say their own thing.